# Is there zend bootstrap analog in yii?

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii

I want to try db connection to check is db available. In zend I can place my code in boostrap file and wrap it in try catch.

How to implement this in yii? 
Is in yii analog of zend boostrap?

**UPD:** db is mongo, yii extention for working with db is a [directmongosuite](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/directmongosuite/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that I find appropriate solution:

1. Need to prohibit auto connect in config file:

   'components' => array(
           'edms' => array(
               'class' => 'EDMSConnection',
               'dbName' => 'homeweb',
               'server' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
               'options' => array('connect' => false)
           )
   )
2. all controllers should extend one custom controller (`BaseController` for example).
3. Need to write own `public function beforeAction` method where I can add boostrap code.

   ```
   class BaseController extends CController
   {
       public $layout = '//layouts/main';
       public $navigationMenu = array();
       public $breadcrumbs = array();

       public function beforeAction($action)
       {
           try {
               Yii::app()->edmsMongo()->connect();
           } catch (Exception $e) {
               die('Cannot connect to the database server. Please Try again later.');
           }
           $isGuest = Yii::app()->user->isGuest;
           $this->navigationMenu = $this->_getNavigationMenu($isGuest);
           return parent::beforeAction($action);
       }
   ```
4. In the `beforeAction` method need to add `return true` or execute parent's method.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap in yii is pretty much the index.php file under public_html or the yiic.php file (for command line applications).

You will probably have to separate the creating of the application instance and running it (by default it does both on 1 line), so you can do your try/catch between the calls.

Just try to fetch the app component, the mongo plugin will throw an exception if it can't open the connection:

```
try
{
    Yii::app()->mongoDb;
}
...
```

or Yii::app()->getComponent('mongoDb');